# stretching/shrinking elements inside of a div to fit its max width?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a row of buttons stretch to fit the width of a div element. However, I cannot find a way to do this. I would preferably not have to specify a div for every x amount of objects, and simply have it "just work," but if it's the only way then I don't mind.

I have been looking at different posts here but cannot find one for this specific purpose. Ideally, I would like it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ6g5.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about put them  in a container which has display: flex and justify-content: space-between.

space-between means that the elements are placed with one up against the left side and one up against the right side and any free space divided equally between the gaps. It will wrap if container isn't big enough. Of course this means your gaps will be different on different 'lines' but that's inevitable if the buttons have varying widths.

```css
.container {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2.abcdefg</button>
  <button>3.xyz</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5.ghijklmnopq</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a ton! though, is there any way to make the margin act like space between?

Comment: Not sure which margin you mean. You could investigate different justify-content options - space-around and space-evenly will distribute some space at the ends too but your image had the ends aligned so I don't think that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.buttons
{
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Ok</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Social Media</button>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Social Media</button>
    <button>Ok</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Ok</button>
    <button>Social Media</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```css
div /*this is example div dont mind this */ {
height: auto;
width: 500px;
background: blue;
} 

#random button /* all buttons in div with id random will have this properties*/{ 
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="random">
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```